# image resizing not working (image ar not saved in size folder (small, medium,....)

Tags: javascript, php, html

i've got a little problem on my website, the images I upload are only upload to the folder containing their normal size, but nothing in the other folders that are supposed to contain their other sizes.

Here is an example of the use of my function that resizes the images and that saves them

I send to him:

```
Resizer::resize($file,ROOT.DS.'media/img/small/'.$namecustom,50,50,'crop');

public static function resize($img_source,$img_destination,$max_width,$max_height,$option,$quality=90){

    $extension = Resizer::getExtension($img_source);
    if($extension == false){
        return;
    }

    $new_image = Resizer::createImage($extension,$img_source);

    $width_img  = imagesx($new_image);
    $height_img = imagesy($new_image);

    $tabDimension = Resizer::getDimension($width_img,$height_img,$max_width,$max_height,$option);
    $new_width = $tabDimension['new_width'];
    $new_height = $tabDimension['new_height'];

    $img_transparent = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    imagecopyresampled($img_transparent,$new_image,0,0,0,0,$new_width,$new_height,$width_img,$height_img);

    if($option == 'crop'){
        Resizer::crop($new_width,$new_height,$max_width,$max_height,$img_transparent,$img_destination,$quality);
    }elseif($option == 'stick'){
        $img_transparent =  Resizer::createTransparentImage($max_width , $max_height);
        imagecopyresampled($img_transparent,$new_image,0,0,0,0,$new_width,$new_height,$width_img,$height_img);
        Resizer::stick($new_width,$new_height,$max_width,$max_height,$img_transparent,$img_destination,$quality);
    }else{
        Resizer::saveImage($img_transparent,$img_destination,$quality);
    }
}

public static function crop($new_width,$new_height,$max_width,$max_height,$img_transparent,$img_destination,$quality){
            $cropStartX = ($new_width - $max_width)/2;
            $cropStartY = ( $new_height - $max_height )/2;
            $crop = $img_transparent;

    $img_transparent = Resizer::createTransparentImage($max_width , $max_height);
    if(imagecopyresampled($img_transparent, $crop , 0, 0, $cropStartX, $cropStartY, $max_width, $max_height , $max_width, $max_height)){
        Resizer::saveImage($img_transparent,$img_destination,$quality);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You haven't actually included the definition of the `Resizer::saveImage()` method. I presume it just calls `imagejpeg()` or one of the other methods to write an image file, but it would be helpful to include the code given that your problem is with files not being saved. Also, have you checked that the web server has the required permission to write to the desired destination?

Comment: normally yes, and also, it worked very well before.

Comment: There is a link to download the file with full script.

https://zt-protect.com/link/dk1JNTJOdWRNUllYRFM5RGNWTnJzR0pIcm9YbVJYb3kxeGIxcGp4ZkJrcz0=